# Designing a questiion-and-answer system that is flexible and efficient

Tags: c#, sql, design-patterns, database-design

I've been working on a dynamic question-and-answers system, but I'm having trouble creating a efficient AND flexible design for this system.  I'd love to know if there's an established design pattern or any recommendations for designing this system.

### What I'm trying to do

I have a set of questions.  After answering them, another set of questions are shown, **depending on the answers to the previous set**.  This repeats, until no more questions are needed.

The question answers are all boolean, multiple-choice, or numeric.

**The important part** is that most questions are only shown when a specific set of criteria is met, based on the previous answers.
I need the criteria to support mainly boolean logic, such as And, Or, Not, Equals, Greater Than, and Less Than.

For example, let's say I have already received answers to questions such as `Age`, `Gender`, and `State`.
One of the next questions is `In School?`, but it should ONLY be displayed if: `Age < 30 AND Gender=Male AND (State = CA OR State = NY)`

#### Has anyone heard of a similar design pattern?  How would you approach this design?

### Background Information

#### I tried Database columns

At first, we only had 3 initial questions, so we just used 3 columns to filter the second set of questions.

However, our business needs grew and we started needing more initial questions, added more columns, and put more logic within those filters.

This quickly became too rigid and cumbersome.

#### I tried a Logic Interpreter

Our second attempt to make the system more flexible: store the filtering logic as JavaScript, and run a JavaScript interpreter to filter the results.

This worked pretty well for flexibility, but retrieving thousands of rows from the database and interpreting the scripts was extremely inefficient and performed too poorly for production.

#### I tried a Hybrid

We finally combined the two approaches, and came up with something feasable.
We first filtered our list based on several hard-coded database columns, and further filtered the list with the JavaScript interpreter.

This hybrid system still has many drawbacks:

- The logic is in 2 different systems (SQL database logic and JavaScript interpreter)
- Interpreting the JavaScript is slow, and is probably overkill for the simple boolean logic needed
- The system is very difficult to maintain, especially because the JavaScript logic must always be written by a developer.

I'd really like to hear suggestions on how to improve this design.

#### Other Info

My database is MS SQL Server, the backend is .NET C#, and the JavaScript interpreter is JINT.  The UI implementation is not important, but is a AJAX enabled website used to ask and answer these questions.

Comment: Coconut, that's a really unusual reason for a downvote. You like answering questions that are only one sentence long?

Comment: Did you ever consider `NoSQL` database approach? Like `MongoDB` for example.?

Comment: @Coconut I moved the actual question to the top, and labelled everything else "Background Info".  Hope that helps ease reading.

Comment: @Tigran We have used `MongoDB` elsewhere in our system. If a non-relational database can provide a good solution, I'm all ears!

Comment: @ScottRippey I have some similar requirement and try to build a system like what you mentioned, Could you please share your final solution with me. I want to know the design. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had to do something similar in the past for a medical system and due to its complexity, we resorted to reuse the rule engine that support multi-classification decision tree. I remember that I came across a nice simple design about this and managed to dig out the link.

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip139.html?page=1

The design is loosely coupled from the data storage, so making it easy to fit into your existing solution design.

Comment: That's a great article, thanks.  I totally think of tax preparation software when I think of my requirements.  It was great to read someone else's experience with creating a similar system.

Comment: In this example, I see that each **answer** has a **consequence** that corresponds to another question.  How do you think I could build the logic that associates a specific **combination** of answers to a single question?

Comment: If this is a interactive questionnaire, theoretically by the time you reach a particular question (consequence), a number of previous criteria have been met e.g Q1 -> answer A, Consequence Q3 -> answer B, Consequence 7 -> answer A, Consequence Q8, therefore Q8 is really a result of associative conditions (combination of answers). If you have to evaluate multiple criteria in analysis to derive an answer, then you should look at implementing decision tree algorithm

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you are building a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Each state corresponds to a question, and based on the answer you move on to a new question. The same question might occur in several separate states.

In your example the begin state would be the question "State?", and if it the answer is "CA" we move to the next state with the question "Rent or Own?". For any answer to that question the next state will be the question "Age?" since there is no further sub-questions for the "State?"->"Rent or Own?" path.

For you db model you need a state table and a relation table between states, ie:

table states:

- id (int)
- question (varchar)
- type (set[text, boolean, int])

table state_state:

- fromState (int)
- toState(int)
- answerType (set[any, equals, greater, ...])
- answer (varchar)

In your code you only need to know the current state, ask the question, make a query to state_state and compare the results to the answer given to know what the id of the next state will be and thus the next question.

If you have a lot of states with the same question you can create a questions table and relate it to state.

If you have several 'begin questions' you can either have one state machine and tie the end questions to the next 'begin question', or you could have several state machines.

Comment: After you edited your question I see that this might not be what you are looking for. However, you might be able to use the idea anyway if you automatically change state if the question has already been answered. This of course requires you to keep the questions in a separate table.

Comment: This is a very interesting way to look at it!

Comment: I had a hard time wording the question ... I first wrote it focused on the question path, but after some thought, I realized the real tricky part is the conditional criteria logic.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement to create custom surveys. We have 3 tables, question, response and questionroute. the response table allows you to create multiple answers to each question, and the questionroute table allows you to select the next question based on a specific response.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question]
(
QuestionID uniqueidentifier,
[Text] varchar(512)
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Response]
(
ResponseID uniqueidentifier,
QuestionID uniqueidentifier,
[Text] varchar(512)
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuestionRoute]
(
QuestionRouteID uniqueidentifier,
QuestionID uniqueidentifier,
ResponseID uniqueidentifier,
NextQuestionID uniqueidentifier
)
```

Comment: The question says "another **set of questions** are shown, depending on the **answers** to the previous set".  Your solution is nice for a navigating one question at a time, but difficult to apply for sets of questions.  Also, this won't support the whole boolean logic thing.

Comment: You're right, I missed the bit of 3 questions asked at a time. I suppose you could add another table for "QuestionSet", but then the boolean stuff is still missing... :)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution.  The boolean stuff is an important part of the question, but I appreciate knowing how others solved similar problems!